# Считывание информации с COM-порта в Python

Tags: python

Есть задачка у меня: Нужно в Python протестировать железячку по протоколу Modbus. Опыта можно сказать почти нету. Дак я вот начал с малого. Железка подключена к компьютеру через преобразователь USB-RS485. Ну а в компе этот преобразователь естественно виден как COM3.

код у меня вот такой:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout = 10, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
print(ser.name)
a = ser.readline()
print('Вот так:', a)
```

выводит в консоле вот такое сообщение:

> \x0b\x03\x00\x00\x00xEB\x0b\x03\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00s\xc0\x00\x00/t\xff\xda/t\xff\xda\x1b\xf9\xff\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00

Я так понял, это в формате HEX?

Comment: Я немного увлекаюсь программированием микроконтроллеров, но с COM-портом не приходилось работать. Вообще, такие интерфейсы обычно принимают/отдают байты (от 0x00 до 0xff). А что с этими байтами делать - это уже Ваши решения. Вполне возможно, что Вы хотите закодировать в этих байтах не строковые команды. Скорее всего Вам придется использовать что-то подобное `for line in ser.read():`

Comment: А с библиотекой pymodbus не сталкивались?

Comment: Нет, пока не довелось. Мне кажется, что Вы изобретаете велосипед. Тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/281430/ есть перечисление программ, которые можно использовать для считывания ответов и формирования запросов.

Comment: Вобщем, подобрал библиотеку minimalmodbus и все пошло как по маслу. Потихоньку разобрался)))